# Methods implemented in inner class for an outer class implementing interface

Tags: java, interface, inner-classes

Say that we have an interface:

```java
public interface SomeInterface {
  public void A();
  public void B();
}
```

and we have a class:

```java
public class SomeClass {
  public void A(){...};

  private class SomeInnerClass {
    public void B(){...};
  }
}
```

And I need SomeClass to implement SomeInterface,  but the required method "B" in SomeClass is implemented in an inner class. What can I do to make SomeClass successfully implement SomeInterface?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You can't. You have to implement the interface methods in the class that you are claiming does so. You could implement them as delegates to a permanent instance of the inner class, but what exactly is the point?

Answer (score 1):

Inside `SomeClass` create an instance of the `SomeInnerClass` and use its implementation for B() method.

like that:

```
public class SomeClass {
  private SomeInnerClass someInnerClass = new SomeInnerClass();

  public void A(){
      ...                    // self implementation
  };

  public void B(){
      someInnerClass.B();    // Inner class implementation
  };

  private class SomeInnerClass {
    public void B(){...};
  }
}
```